# Doubt on limit set of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose, the initial value of a 1st order ODE lies in the limit point set for the ODE. Is it true that any solution for the ODE (value $\forall t$) also lies in the limit set ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided that the ODE has enough regularity for solutions to be unique (i.e. no branching of trajectories). Under this condition, $\omega$-limit sets are invariant under flow maps $\phi_t$, for positive and negative $t$. For a proof, see [Omega limit set is invariant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/259994/).