# Limit set of a non-autonomous system is not invariant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, set-invariance

I am trying to understand why the (positive or omega) limit set of a non-autonomous dynamical system 
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=f(t,x)
\label{ftx}
\tag{1}
\end{equation} is not necessarily (positively) invariant. Assume that $f$ is piecewise continuous in $t$ for each fixed $x$, and that $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $x$ uniformly over $t$.

I have seen the proof for the autonomous case [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259994/omega-limit-set-is-invariant), and I imagine that, for the non-autonomous case, a set $\bar{\omega}$ may belong to the positive limit set of \ref{ftx} for a given initial time $\bar{t}$, but if the initial time is changed to some $\hat{t}$, then it is possible that the solution will enter $\bar{\omega}$ and leave it.

Am I correct? Or is there something I'm missing that will break in the [aforementioned proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259994/omega-limit-set-is-invariant)?

Comment: Take $$ \dot{x} = \frac{1}{1 + t^2}.$$ What are "$\omega$-limit sets"  in this case?  Are they invariant?

Comment: @user539887 for the example you give, the $\lim_{t\to \infty}\phi(t,t_0,x_0)=\pi/2+x_0-\arctan(t_0)$, right? So your point is that the limit sets may depend on $t_0$ and, consequently, may not be invariant?

Comment: Yes, that was my intention.